# how do I get around a 'certificate has expired' error code

Tags: python, pandas, url

I have been working with a data set from the machine learning repository from UCI, I have been working with this code for about 5 weeks now. I am trying to continue to work with this data set and when I read in the data as I have been with the following code:

```
import numpy as np ##Import necassary packages
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
from sklearn.preprocessing import *
url2="https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data" #Reading in Data from a freely and easily available source on the internet
Adult = pd.read_csv(url2, header=None, skipinitialspace=True)
```

I receive a 'certificate has expired' error code. I have been back to the site where I received the data and was able to download the data set. How can I read in the dataset from the website without receiving this error code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate is expired.
Try using http instead of https

http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data

However, http exposes data to some security vulnerabilities.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS#Difference_from_HTTP

Comment: Thank you! when I returned to the website to re-copy the address it did not update, what did you do differently?

Comment: I am afraid I don't get your question.
Do you mean, the adult.data file? If so, you will need to ask for the maintainers of UCI server. ;-)